# Редирект на главную страницу .htaccess Open Server (Apache)

Tags: .htaccess, редирект

В общем, есть игра морской бой. Допустим, вот такой урл. http://play/game/
При инициализации пользователю id игры и его личный id. В общем, url становится примерно таким http://play/game/placement/10/Mkdmasdasd
Нужно, чтобы при обновлении страницы данные о расположении кораблей загружались с сервера. Но эт не проблема. Проблема в том, что при обновлении стили нас странице перестают работать. Видимо, их тоже надо как-то редиректить вместе с изображениям. Кто-нибудь может подсказать, что писать в .htaccess?

Comment: поясните, каким образом вы обновляете страницу?

Comment: При вставке стилей вы используете относительный или абсолютный путь? Можете код вставки стилей для начала добавить? Сервер на сколько я понимаю у вас сейчас локально запущен по адресу http://play?